Ubuntu upgrade 22.04 to 24.04 - Not enough free disk space on /boot
During the update I got a message:

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 239 M free space
on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 39.1 M of disk
space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt
autoremove' and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in
/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your
initramfs.

 root@localhost # df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       468M  242M  191M  56% /boot

 root@localhost # ls -lah /boot
total 235M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Oct 29 10:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4.0K Dec  1  2022 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 256K Jul  5 09:53 config-5.15.0-118-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 256K Sep 27 18:21 config-5.15.0-124-generic
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Oct 18 06:08 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   29 Oct 18 06:07 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-124-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 100M Oct 29 10:41 initrd.img-5.15.0-118-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 100M Oct 29 10:40 initrd.img-5.15.0-124-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   29 Oct 18 06:08 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.15.0-118-generic
drwx------  2 root root  16K May 19  2020 lost+found
-rw-------  1 root root 6.0M Jul  5 09:53 System.map-5.15.0-118-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6.0M Sep 27 18:21 System.map-5.15.0-124-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 Oct 18 06:07 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-124-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  12M Jul  5 10:17 vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  12M Sep 27 19:47 vmlinuz-5.15.0-124-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 Oct 18 06:08 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic

 root@localhost # uname -r
5.15.0-124-generic

The question is: will system boot after I delete /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-118-generic, /boot/System.map-5.15.0-118-generic, /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic? After deleting, shall I point initrd.img.old and vmlinuz.old to the same current 124 version?

You should NOT be doing any of those things manually. You should be telling apt to remove the 5.15.0-118 kernel package, and apt will handle the rest cleanly.

This question is similar to: How do I free up more space in /boot?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

sudo apt-get purge 5.15.0-118-generic and sudo apt autoremove removed unused kernel and has freed up space on /boot!

In the future I recommend using Bleachbit to clean old kernels etc... It's a must have app.  https://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux
